# fix filenames with wrong starting and ending character(s) in Bash, mass renaming

Tags: linux, bash, files, regular-expression, rename

I need to rename a lot of files by removing the 1st and the last characters (before `.ext`).

WRONG>

```
'1st moto ride [Aug '99]'.mp4
'Samuel' Song'.mp3
'Plane Landing'.avi
'"Ode" (sort of) to the Sun'.pdf
'The Divine Comedy [1308, Alighieri D.]'.txt
'100 ways to jump off the Moon'.wav
'[1979] Ста́лкер'.mkv
```

RIGHT>

```
1st moto ride [Aug '99].mp4
Samuel' Song.mp3
Plane Landing.avi
"Ode" (sort of) to the Sun.pdf
The Divine Comedy [1308, Alighieri D.].txt
100 ways to jump off the Moon.wav
[1979] Ста́лкер.mkv
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure those single-quote characters are in the filenames, and not just something the `ls` command is displaying as it outputs the filenames to your terminal window?

Comment: @NasirRiley - but that would then wrap the extension as well, no? It wouldn't stop at the `.ext`

Comment: @tink Yes, it can but that can depend on how it was created , the coding, etc. It's possible that they are part of the filename but it's best to be sure so that he doesn't expect it to work on other files where that's not the case.

Comment: The Fedora and Debian families of operating systems including the latest major releases of Fedora, RHEL, Alma Linux, Rocky Linux, Debian, Ubuntu, and Mint all place single quotes around filenames with white space in the shell. Gentoo, Arch, Mageia, and Solus Linux do the same. OpenSuse doesn't. Those are all of the distributions that I have in my lab for testing. In your case, the quotes don't cover the extension so perhaps they are a part of the filename but it's best to determine for sure. If you copy the file to rename it as something else with the same extension, do the quotes remain?

Comment: @SottoVoce,@NasirRiley: Yes, the single quotes are actually part of the name of the file(s); I forgot to metion that I posted the actual output indeed: " $ ls -1N " or " $ find . -iname "\'*" ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these single quotes aren't some impossible to explain `ls` artifact but actually part of the file names.

Further assuming that you have (p)rename installed (the perl utility):

```
ls
''\''1st moto ride [Aug '\''99]'\''.mp4'
rename "s/^'//;s/'\.(.*)$/.\$1/" *
ls
'1st moto ride [Aug '\''99].mp4'
```

Note that in this output the single quotes on either end of the filename in the 2nd `ls`'s output are indeed `ls` artifacts.

A few explanatory words regarding the tool & the expressions.

It uses perl regex.  The `s///` syntax is basically the same as in `sed`, except for the `$1` for backreferences. You can use more than one expression on one line if you separate them by `;`.

In other words: search for a leading `'` and replace it with nothing.
Then search for a `'` preceding a literal `.`, capture everything after the `.` and replace all that matches with a `.` and the captured part.

Commonly I'd use single quotes to wrap the perl REs, but since we're trying to replace a single quote (and trying to escape that is VERY ugly) I used double quotes. That meant that I had to escape the `$1` in the replacement section (otherwise it would become the empty string from the missing bash variable.

Comment: I stall cannot vote, so THANK YOU! It works perfectly. I forgot to metion that I posted the actual output indeed: " $ ls -1N " or " $ find . -iname "\'*" ".

Comment: @dAllARA You're welcome - and you may not be able to upvote, but you **should** be able to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Sure! Answer accepted! :)